# JSON Schema validation for js files

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, jsonschema

Today I learned about JSON schema in vscode https://docs.joshuatz.com/cheatsheets/js/json-schema/. I would like to apply that to a file in our work, but it is not a simple json file but is a js export. Structure like

```
module.exports = {
"first":"Joe",
"last":"Smith"
}
```

Can I apply json schema to a file that looks like that?

Comment: ofc yes, you just have to remove the `module.exports = ` and the rest is valis `.json` file, please visit [JSON.ORG][(https://www.json.org/json-en.html) for more info and also, please remove this question since it's not something that others can benefit from.

Comment: so then the answer is no, if I need it to be a js file with an export, then I cannot do this.

Comment: can you clarify what is the objective you want to reach and what is the issue ?

Comment: I see how extensions can add json validation to json files. But for other reasons I don't want to go into, my file is a json object that is exported in a js file. Can I use json schema to validate this file, but just the object portion? Should I be looking at intellisense or something else to write the validator?

Comment: well since it's just the validation that you're after, you can simply parse the file using any language you're using to just remove the portion of `JS` and keep the `JSON` part, ofc after that you'll need to validate it, use [pre-built validators](https://json-schema.org/implementations.html) to validate it using you preferred language.

Comment: I was hoping to use the jsonValidation feature of VSCode extensions. I think I can't use this for this situation but could find an alternative.

Comment: use [prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode), it can format JS code, and json is also valid JS code (even more so in your case, cause it's a .js file)

Comment: not my use case. I am looking for autocompletion/ key validation.

Comment: There are perfectly valid reasons to want to validate js files using JSON schema. For example, `rc-config-loader` allows .json, .yml, or .js files.

I'm sorry I don't have an answer but it's a great question.